# Protractor redirects and times out immediately after loading page

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to write some e2e specs for an AngularJS application. I have one Jasmine spec in `test/e2e/test_spec.js`:

```
describe('basic functionality', function() {
  it('loads the home page', function() {
    browser.get('/');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/localhost/);
  });
});
```

Terminal output when the spec is run:

```
> protractor protractor.config.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
basic functionality
  loads the home page - fail


Failures:

  1) basic functionality loads the home page
   Message:
     Error: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
Wait timed out after 10013ms
   Stacktrace:
     Error: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
Wait timed out after 10013ms
    at Array.forEach (native)
From: Task: waiting for page to load for 10000ms
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/jdent/swamp-bunny/test/e2e/test_spec.js:3:13)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/jdent/swamp-bunny/test/e2e/test_spec.js:2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jdent/swamp-bunny/test/e2e/test_spec.js:1:63)

Finished in 10.955 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

While the console is sitting on `[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver`, Chrome opens and displays the index page for a fraction of a second, then changes to a blank page with `data:text/html,<html></html>` in the address bar.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Here is my `protractor.config.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  specs: 'test/e2e/**/*_spec.js',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    isVerbose: true
  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.driver.get("http://localhost:8100");
  }
};
```

My webdriver-manager stuff seems to be up to date, although the tool doesn't seem to have a way to output version numbers.

```
> webdriver-manager status
selenium standalone is up to date
chromedriver is up to date
IEDriver is not present
```

Why is the spec failing?

**Edit:** This is what is printed to the terminal when `onPrepare` is commented out:

```
> protractor protractor.config.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was:
unknown
basic functionality
  loads the home page - fail


Failures:

  1) basic functionality loads the home page
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 34.27 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

**Edit 2:** When I do `browser.get("http://google.com")`, Chrome briefly shows the `data:` and `data:text/html,<html></html>` pages, redirects to Google, then times out looking for Angular.

```
> protractor protractor.config.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
basic functionality
  loads the home page - fail


Failures:

  1) basic functionality loads the home page
   Message:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://google.com/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://google.com/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
    at Array.forEach (native)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/jdent/swamp-bunny/test/e2e/test_spec.js:2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jdent/swamp-bunny/test/e2e/test_spec.js:1:63)

Finished in 12.186 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: What if you comment out `onPrepare()` in your config?

Comment: @alecxe Almost the same thing, except the browser starts on a blank page with the url `data:` before redirecting to `data:text/html,<html></html>`. Running repeatedly it alternates between an error similar to the one in the question and one with the message `timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete` and a stacktrace of `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out - `stacktrace of undefined` - could you provide this kind of a stacktrace too?

Comment: Can you also replace `browser.get("/");` with smth like `browser.get("https://google.com");` and see what output you'll get? Thanks.

Comment: Updated question with outputs. When I do `browser.get("http://localhost:8100")`, my page loads and the test passes.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update. So it looks like `browser.get('/')` is the problem line causing weird errors?

Comment: Yep! It looks like any url I give to `browser.get` needs to be, like, an actual url. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100'` in your `protractor.config.js` file. From the [Protractor Reference Config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js):

> A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get() with relative paths will be prepended with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sporadic  open bug in protractor https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5103

Instead of this

```
browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
```

Using this has solved my issue.

```
browser.driver.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem in chrome. I read somewhere that protractor starts on that `data:text/html,<html></html>` page. Calling `browser.get(...)` navigates away from that page.  My idea was to open chrome already on my base url.  I accomplished that by adding it to the capabilities like this:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--app=www.yourBaseUrl.com']
  }
},
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it seems to have done the trick.